# How to render data from an API using an id (key) to determine what populates?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently pulling data from an API where each user has their own id and an array of data such as forenames, surnames, date of birth, etc.

I've rendered each user into a user list, and I'm hoping to have an onClick for each user in the user list which will then populate fields in a seperate component making up the main view of the page.

How would I go about doing this? I'm really struggling to find guides/advice on how to do this. I feel as though I would need to assign the user id to the overall state of the main view component which would then drive what gets populated - but I'd really appreciate any input from you all on this.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I assume [this is what you are trying to do](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-dan-1jdl0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Your gut feeling is right!
Have a `selectedUser` state object, that is updated with the `onClick`, and then pass that object into the separate component as a prop. When a click occurs, the state will update, and that sub-component will re-render with the new User prop object. :)

Here's a little sample:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState()

  const users = [ // Would get this from your API
    { id: 1, name: "Alice", dob: "01/01/99" },
    { id: 2, name: "Bob", dob: "02/02/97" }
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      {
        // show a button per user in the list
        users.map(user =>
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedUser(user)} key={user.id}>
            {user.name}
          </button>)
      }

      {
        // if selectedUser exists, show the UserView component
        selectedUser && <UserView user={selectedUser} />
      }
    </div>
  );
}

function UserView({user}) {
  console.log(user)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      <p>Date Of Birth: {user.dob}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

See in action here:
https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/62919659#src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't sure if I needed to jump into Redux or something like that (I'm a React.js beginner), but your advice has been super helpful!!

Thanks again :D I'll give this a go!

Comment: Yeah I'd advise to just keep away from redux or other state management until things get so complex that you need to! State handling in react with `useState` is so much easier and gets you pretty far.

Comment: I've spun up a little demo for you: https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/62919659#src/App.js